# Does Terraform apply a life cycle to ignore_change for the S3 bucket event of the SQS type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events, terraform

I have few SQS events in the S3 bucket notification. When i run the operation from Terraform those SQS events are lost as they are not part of state file. I cant use cli to import the events as the terraform will be run several time and it is not a good idea to import all the events everytime after terraform has completed the execution.

I am creating a S3 event from terraform and having a lifecycle to ignore SQS type :

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "lambda_notification" {
bucket = "bucket1"

lambda_function {
  lambda_function_arn = "function_arn"
events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  filter_prefix       = "staging/inbound/Source_Contact/"
  }
 lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [
    "SQS"
  ]
}
  }
```

**I want to know if lifecycle can be used to keep the SQS event**

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the Terraform code forms a [mcve] please? It's hard to understand exactly what is happening from these incomplete snippets.

Answer (score 1):

SQS events to Lambda are consumed on delivery unless they fail and you have a dead letter queue (DLQ) to collect them.

[lifecycle ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes) won't be effective for your use regardless of what you set it to. It doesn't affect content in services, it affects how Terraform deploys resources when it detects changes to the resources versus your module source:

> ignore_changes (list of attribute names) - By default, Terraform detects any difference in the current settings of a real infrastructure object and plans to update the remote object to match configuration.
>
> In some rare cases, settings of a remote object are modified by processes outside of Terraform, which Terraform would then attempt to "fix" on the next run. In order to make Terraform share management responsibilities of a single object with a separate process, the ignore_changes meta-argument specifies resource attributes that
>   Terraform should ignore when planning updates to the associated remote object.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and was able to retain the SQS events created out of tfe and create Lambda events from tfe.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "lambda_notification" {
  bucket = "bucket1"

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "function_arn"
  events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "staging/inbound/Source_Contact/"
    }
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "queue."
    ]
  }
}
```